# Get date format according to the locale in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date, format

There is a very simple problem. I have a locale identifier, en, en_US, cs_CZ or whatever. I just need to get the date-time format for that locale. I know I can easily format any timestamp or date object according to the locale. But I need just the **string representation of the date format**, let's say a regular expression. Is there any function managing this functionality? I haven't found any so far...

Exapmle:

```
$locale = "en_US";
$format = the_function_i_need($locale);
echo $format; // prints something like "month/day/year, hour:minute"
```

Comment: I agree with @dagon. and setting PHP to follow UTC will make it much easier.

Comment: @Dagon I believe your comment is more accurate, you should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

converted from comment:

you will have to build an array with a list of the possibilities.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country should help.

post the function somewhere when done, i'm sure it would come in handy for others

Comment: this is advice, but not answer

Comment: i was asked to turn comment in to answer, and so i did.

Answer (score 11):

```
function getDateFormat($locale)
{
    $formatter = new IntlDateFormatter($locale, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
    if ($formatter === null)
        throw new InvalidConfigException(intl_get_error_message());

    return $formatter->getPattern();
}
```

Make shure you install [intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php).

Comment: To me this is the best answer - universal, short and working. Though those ICU formats seem to be pretty short on possibilities. I'd need something like  IntlDateFormatter::SHORT with 4 digit years and leading 0s.

Comment: I didn't pick that up from the manual right away (it says `"Medium style (Jan 12, 1952)"`), but apparently the IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM is just what I needed (leading zeros, 5-digit year)

Comment: this was the correct answer for me in this day and age. modern api, no screwing around with `setlocale()`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to do the same thing myself. Instead of building an array of all the countries, how about using regex to determine the format?

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "us_US");

// returns 'mdy'
$type1 = getDateFormat();

setlocale(LC_TIME, "fi_FI");

// returns 'dmy'
$type2 = getDateFormat();

setlocale(LC_TIME, "hu_HU");

// returns 'ymd'
$type3 = getDateFormat();

/**
 * @return string
 */
function getDateFormat()
{
    $patterns = array(
        '/11\D21\D(1999|99)/',
        '/21\D11\D(1999|99)/',
        '/(1999|99)\D11\D21/',
    );
    $replacements = array('mdy', 'dmy', 'ymd');

    $date = new \DateTime();
    $date->setDate(1999, 11, 21);

    return preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, strftime('%x', $date->getTimestamp()));
}
```

Comment: Some years later: set locale like above, just skip the getDateFormat function and use ```strftime("%x", $timestamp)```

Comment: $likes += 1;
//Just in time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) in conjunction with [`setlocale()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php). Seems like it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's the opposite way. If not, I don't follow your idea. Could you write a short example, please?

Comment: ah, I think I understand now. `strftime()` will convert the time and language of the output, but for the actual format like "yyyy-mm-dd" in Canada as opposed to "dd/mm/yyyy" in Albania I believe you will have to use Dagon's approach. seems like there should be a function that does this...