# How to change date format from US to French date format?

Tags: php, html, laravel

**Blade.php**

```
<tr>
   <td class="lesDates"> 
       <?php            
          $date = strtotime($formation['annee_obtention']);
          echo date('D / M / Y ', $date);  
       ?>    
   </td>
</tr>
```

I would like to show it in French long format.

Comment: What is `french long format`? Can you provide an example please?

Comment: February 2, 2020 ==> 
french format : 2 février 2020

Comment: Okay, so you want the `locale` to be set to french then the `date` function will just need the appropriate values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change month name to french](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309960/change-month-name-to-french)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a date format in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-a-date-format-in-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php get locale specific date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737272/php-get-locale-specific-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

in laravel you can use Carbon to managing date or time in you application.
check out this https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

in carbon,you can format the date using simple code. example in Carbon docs

```
// Let say Martin from Paris and John from Chicago play chess
$martinDateFactory = new Factory([
'locale' => 'fr_FR',
'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',
]);
$johnDateFactory = new Factory([
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'timezone' => 'America/Chicago',
]);
// Each one will see date in his own language and timezone

// When Martin moves, we display things in French, but we notify John in English:
$gameStart = Carbon::parse('2018-06-15 12:34:00', 'UTC');
$move = Carbon::now('UTC');
$toDisplay = $martinDateFactory->make($gameStart)->isoFormat('lll')."\n".
$martinDateFactory->make($move)->calendar()."\n";
$notificationForJohn = $johnDateFactory->make($gameStart)->isoFormat('lll')."\n".
$johnDateFactory->make($move)->calendar()."\n";
echo $toDisplay;
/*
15 juin 2018 12:34
Aujourd’hui à 12:40
*/

echo $notificationForJohn;
/*
Jun 15, 2018 12:34 PM
Today at 12:40 PM
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Repository :
https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-date

To install this library you can follow these instructions:
https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-date#installation

Using a library as Laravel-Date you will just need to set the language of the app in the Laravel app config file and use its functions to format the date as you want.

**Set the language in /app/config/app.php**

```
'locale' => 'fr',
```

**Examples:**

```
use Jenssegers\Date\Date;

Date::setLocale('nl'); //Change this to your preferred locale

echo Date::now()->format('l j F Y H:i:s'); // zondag 28 april 2013 21:58:16

echo Date::parse('-1 day')->diffForHumans(); // 1 dag gelede
```

**Hindi Example:**

```
 Date::setLocale('hi');

 echo Date::now()->format('l j F Y H:i:s');
```

**French Example:**

```
 Date::setLocale('fr');

 echo Date::now()->format('l j F Y H:i:s');
```