# Change pubDate Language PHP

Tags: php, html, date, web, rss

I just embed a RSS Feed on a website. I used PHP for it.

My problem is, that the output for the pubDate is in englisch, but i want it in german. f.E. Thu, 03 Nov 2022 08:00:00 GMT. I just want to change the language of the days. So from Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun -> Mo, Di, Mi, Do, Fr, Sa, So

Is there a easy way to change it?

I tried to change the language with that, but it doesn't changed any

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8');

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP 8.1: strftime() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70930824/php-8-1-strftime-is-deprecated)

Comment: Where is your code? How are you generating the date? How can we help without seeing your code? :-) Have you tried all the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845554/php-date-get-name-of-the-months-in-local-language, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737272/php-get-locale-specific-date-format, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1114488/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/8744952/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827514/get-date-format-according-to-the-locale-in-php, etc?